# CSS3: first letter, vertical-align: super and changed height

Tags: html, css

I want to create a simple list ( without images ).
First letter of last element in list should have "vertical-align: super;" style, but when I do this the height of paragraph is increasing.

```
#third::first-letter {
    vertical-align: super;
}
```

How to fix it without knowing the font size and paragraph height ?
[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/397LzgL0/)

Comment: Use only : instead :: for first-letter pseudo-element

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One possible option to move the [`::first-letter`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors-3/#first-letter) vertically without affecting the height of the box, is to `float` the pseudo-element and give a negative `margin-top` to it:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/397LzgL0/7/)**

```css
#third::first-letter {
    margin-top: -.5em;
    float: left;
}
```

---

```css
* {margin:0;padding:0;}
html {font-size: 200%;}
#first {background-color:pink;}
#second {background-color:aqua;}
#third {background-color:lightgreen; margin-top: 1em;}

#third::first-letter {
    margin-top: -.5em;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<p id="first">My list:</p>
<p id="second">|-> not last element</p>

<p id="third">|-> last element</p>
```

---

However as [@Alohci](https://stackoverflow.com/users/42585/alohci) pointed it out in comments, in Firefox `::first-letter` doesn't match the first character if the it is not a *letter* or digit.

Therefore, in this particular case where the first character is not a letter/digit but a pipe `|`, we'd better add that character by using `::before` pseudo-element, so that we can style it properly:

**[Example Here](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/397LzgL0/6/)**

```css
#third::before {
    content: "|";
    margin-top: -.5em;
    float: left;
}
```

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0}
html {font-size: 200%;}
#first{background-color:pink;}
#second{background-color:aqua;}
#third{background-color:lightgreen; margin-top: 1em;}

#second::before,
#third::before {
    content: "|";
}

#third::before {
    margin-top: -.5em;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<p id="first">My list:</p>
<p id="second">-> not last element</p>

<p id="third">-> last element</p>
```

Comment: Can I use z-index for it ( see #third without margin-top:.5em ) ?

Comment: @Eiji For the `::first-letter` pseudo-element?

Comment: @Eiji No, because `z-index` is only applicable to positioned elements and `position` property doesn't have any effect on `::first-letter`. But instead, you can position the `#third` element itself as `relative` and add a `z-index` to it. Or set the position and a higher `z-index` to the `#second` element instead.

Comment: Warning - this example does not work in Firefox, probably because | is not a letter (or a digit).

Comment: @Alohci Not sure why FF do that. It is not mentioned in the spec that UAs should/must apply `::first-letter` only on letters — at least in my knowledge.

Comment: @HashemQolami - It's not clear in the current standards. But [Selectors 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-pseudo-4/#first-letter-pseudo) says that the ::first-letter pseudo-element represents the first *typographic letter unit*. The latest editors draft of CSSText defines [typographic letter unit](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-3/#typographic-letter-unit) as belonging to one of the Letter or Number general categories in Unicode. i.e. one of categories Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, Nd, Nl, No. Unicode's [scripts.txt](http://unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/Scripts.txt) document says that `|` is category Sm.

Comment: ... Correction/Clarification `::first-letter` is defined in "CSS Pseudo-Elements Module Level 4", referenced by Selectors 4, not directly defined in it.

Comment: @Alohci Thank you for these useful information. It makes sense now. It seems FF has pioneered to implement pseudo-elements module level 4.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `negative margin-top`, `line-height` is a better solution. Using `line-height` there is no empty space below the letter.